# How to check if month end falls on weekend?

Tags: linux, bash, date

I need to check and get date of Month end falls on weekend, Could someone help

Answer (score 5):

Using GNU `date`:

```
[[ $(date -d "-$(date +%d)days month" +%u) = [67] ]] && echo 'Month-End falls on weekend'
```

Normally, `date -d "-$(date +%d)days month"` means, minus the days of the current month and add a month to the result; that's actually is:

```
date -d'-XXX days + 1month'
```

where we calculate and get the `XXX` days with `date +%d`.

---

test for *Jan-2021* which ends in weekend:

```
[[ $(date -d "-$(date +%d)days 3month" +%u) = [67] ]] && echo 'Month-End falls on weekend'
```

---

from [man date](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html), `%u` is the FORMAT control for the days of week (1..7); 1 is *Monday*. so change 6 and 7 above based on your region's calendar for days of weekend.

Answer (score 3):

With the `ksh93` shell:

```
month='this month'
month='2020-11'
month='November 2020'
if [[ ${ printf '%(%u)T' "last day in $month"; } = [67] ]]; then
  print "Last day in $month falls on a weekend"
fi
```

With the `zsh` shell, checking that the first day of the month after is either Sunday or Monday:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime

strftime -s month %Y-%m # this month
month=2020-11           # given month

last_day_on_a_weekend() {
  local TZ=UTC0 y m t

  y=${1%-*} m=${1#*-}
  if (( ++m > 12 )); then
    (( y++ )); m=1
  fi
    
  strftime -rs t %Y-%m-%d $y-$m-1
  strftime -s t %u $t

  [[ $t = [71] ]]
}

if last_day_on_a_weekend $month; then
  print "Last day in $month falls on a weekend"
fi
```